# how to integrate forked Smack XMPP repository in android?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have integrated the Smack library (xmpp client) to my android project (using the instruction as specified in https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.3-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide, gradle method). However, there is some change in our system, that i have to forked the current Smack repo on github, and made some modification. The question is, now, how do i integrate those changes in my current project?

Answer (score 0):

Use gradle's composite build future and add your forked Smack as git submodule to your project.

Feel encouraged to contribute any improvements back to Smack.

Comment: hi Flow. thank you for your suggestion. I just have one question. from the instruction of Smack, and some example projects, to import Smack in our project, in build.gradle, we specify
dependencies {
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0-rc3'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0-rc3'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.2.0-rc3'
}
if i do as you suggested (which, i assume, will import the whole smack project), will this affect the size of the apk?